# Angular 2 JWT Authentication and Session Ids

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, sessionid

I am developing an Angular 2 application. The standard authentication method needs seems to be JWT Authentication. However I have to interface with a backend that require session Ids.

Is it possible to use the two methods together? Possible injecting to session Id into the token, and then reading it when the server receives a request?

Comment: _I have to interface with a backend that require session Ids_ what does it mean? Is it serving classic html forms built at server side? How dou you plan to include it in a SPA application?  Or may be you only need a SingleSignOn between the two systems? Please clarify your use case

Comment: It's currently servicing a WCF service used via other clients, hence why it has it's own permissions handling. I do not need to use it as a WCF service but I do need to use it's functionality. I want inject the sessionId from here into the payload of the JWT token. Is this possible?

Comment: After a successful login in WCF service you could issue a JWT with the user info. But do not include the `sessionId`. JWT is stateless, so when you receive a JWT authtentication token you could not access to user session. It is better to include a `sub` claim with the unique identifier of the user